# What are the weaknesses of the Miracle Rogue deck?

Tags: hearthstone

I just played against two Miracle Rogues directly after each other, and both defeated me with ease. I almost felt like a passive observer, there was almost nothing I could have done to change the outcome of the game. They keep killing all my minions, and at some point I just get hit by a shadow-stepped Leeroy and die.

My first instinct was to kill the Gadgetzan Auctioneer, without it they can't pull off their crazy combos. But that is pretty much impossible if they stealth them immediately and you don't have access to spells that can deal that much damage to stealthed targets.

What are the weaknesses of a Miracle Rogue deck? How should I play against this deck, and how can I prevent them from getting off their deadly combos? I'm using a Warlock Zoo deck right now, but I'd be interested in answers that also apply to other decks.

Comment: A very good question. I have been facing these decks a lot myself and struggle to overcome it. I play as a priest, and have had a few wins vs these decks. I try to force them to use the 2 assassinate cards on make-believe important cards. I would then win because I saved my Defender of Argus and used him on Ysera and another minion. The rogue finishing moves are based on Charge minions like Leeroy or on boosting a Questing Adventurer.

Comment: I have heard Miracle Rogues have poor matchups against rush decks. Like aggro pally or warlock. However I do not have enough experience to say for sure.

Comment: Quick thoughts:
#) Rush down the rogue faster than it can kill you.
#) Lots of taunts muck up Leeroy.
#) Mage OTK spell deck, or similar.

Comment: Set him under pressure and force him to waste his spells on your minions. Also he needs time to draw the cards he needs for his deadly combo, so normally you should have killed him before.

Comment: Put on early pressure and you might just be able to kill him off before he gets auctioneer and so on. Otherwise you might wanna do a shadow flame with or without +4/4 if you really want it dead.

Answer (score 11):

1) Rush decks, as mentioned in some of the comments, can flat out kill a miracle rogue deck before it can set up its combo.  Rogues don't have particularly good mass removal.

2) Lots of taunt spread out across multiple creatures.  Some folks recommend divine shields as well (e.g. Sunwalker).  But you don't want to blow all your mana on a single card or the rogue is just going to sap it.  Look for 3-5 health minions, to avoid Backstab one-shots, and to make it card intensive for him to clear your board.

3) Well-timed secrets when you think his combo is coming soon, can stall him or cause him difficulty choosing how to navigate past them.  Ice Block, Vaporize, etc...  Even Counterspell can break up his combo.  He won't want to attempt it until all your secrets are cleared.

Acidic swamp ooze might be useful to nuke some of his removal if he's stacking Deadly Poison on the Assassin's Blade.  Depends on your deck.

Edit (update):

4) Random or Area targeted spells that can take out the Auctioneer while he's Concealed are useful against this deck.

Comment: Remember, a Miracle Rogue have one main combo to kill you : Leeroy + ShadowStep + Leeroy = 6 mana [12 dammages] Leeroy + ShadowStep + Leeroy + cold Blood = 7 mana [16 dammages] Leeroy + ShadowStep + Leeroy + cold Blood + ShadowStep + Leeroy = 9 mana [22 dammages] Leeroy + ShadowStep + Leeroy + cold Blood + ShadowStep + Leeroy + cold blood = 10 mana [26 dammages]

Answer (score 3):

[Loatheb](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Loatheb) is a useful card to have in almost any deck.  Its Battlecry will delay the Miracle combo or slow down the auctioneer card draw for one turn while putting a strong body on the board.  [Nerub'ar Weblord](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Nerub%27ar_Weblord) doesn't fit in every deck, but is generally useful against zoo and will limit the Miracle combo by making Leeroy more expensive to cast.

I agree with spudone about including an Acidic Swamp Ooze.

Comment: Loatheb + bounce cards (such as youthful brewmaster, ancient brewmaster, and shadowstep) can hold off the spell barrage for multiple turns.

Answer (score 1):

Not only Loatheb, [Nerub'ar Weblord](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Nerub'ar_Weblord) is pretty good against miracle rogue, it's cheap, it's better than a cheap taunt because 6 cost Leeroy(or 5 cost arcane golem) can break most of miracle rogue combo(And miracle rogue also uses lots of other cards with battlecry).
Besides that, this card wont be a dead draw in most of cases, since it's also extremely good against zoo, which is really popular at the moment.

Comment: I wrote my original answer before this card was available, but it is an excellent choice.  Just remember that it also affects your own battlecry cards.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind card like Coldlight Oracle or king mukla are extremely good against miracle roge(or OTK mage) in some scenario, because they often hold 8-9 cards and by drawing 2 more cards you basically burn down his 1-2 cards, and sometimes you might discard his core card like leeroy.

Comment: You don't want to even think about playing mukla against either of the decks you mentioned.